# Pygame Output : Black Background

Tags: python, pygame

I want to view my `blit()` however once i add the line `self.screen_dim.fill([255, 255, 255])`
`pygame.display.update()` it overlaps

```
def __init__(self):       
self.width = 500
self.height = 500    
self.screen_dim = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
self.mole = pygame.image.load("mole.png")
self.mole_hit = pygame.image.load("mole-hit.png")
```

I am confused on how to get my pygame screen the images within that function is working however it overlaps if i added a new background color

```
def start(self):

    stat = True
    num_display = 1
    x_array = []
    y_array = []

    for i in self.mole_pos:
        x_array.append(i[0])
        y_array.append(i[1])
    

     while stat:
        Rand_Pos = random.randint(0, 8)
        if num_display == 1:
            self.screen_dim.blit(self.mole, (x_array[Rand_Pos], y_array[Rand_Pos]))

        for Event in pygame.event.get():
            if Event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                stat = False
            if self.mouse_clicked(mouse.get_pos(), self.mole_pos[Rand_Pos]):
                num_display = 0
                self.screen_dim.blit(self.mole_hit, (x_array[Rand_Pos], y_array[Rand_Pos]))
                continue

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ahs nothing to to with `class`. It is just a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw `self.mole_hit` in the application loop rather than the event loop:

```py
def start(self):
    # [...]

    while stat:
        # [...]

        for Event in pygame.event.get():
            if Event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                stat = False
            
        #<--| INDENTATION
    
        if self.mouse_clicked(mouse.get_pos(), self.mole_pos[Rand_Pos]):
            num_display = 0
            self.screen_dim.blit(self.mole_hit, (x_array[Rand_Pos], y_array[Rand_Pos]))

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Indented was applied still displays black color background

Comment: @JustaNewProgrammer Your question is incomprehensible.